# Error in code based off negative numbers. Need possible fix on time calculator

Tags: c++, algorithm, debugging, error-handling

Hi I have created a program in C++, (which I am very new too). This program basically asks the used for two times such as 3:57 and the duration 1:05 and it will tell you the sum and the difference between the two. The problem is I am getting negative remainders such as if I put an input of 1:18 and 10:39 I expect 11:57 and 2:39 but I get 11:57 and -9:-21 as result when I run the program. What should I do? This is for an assignment and we cannot use if statements. The instructions say if we are having this problem we should "
This is easily done by adding a day (or two or three) to before when calculating the difference." I do not know what this means and have been struggling on this. i pass most tests besides when the  time goes negative
code is below:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;

int run()
{
    cout<< STUDENT << "-" << ASSIGNMENT << ":";
    cout<< "CEREAL BOX CALCULATOR" << endl;
    cout<< string(50, '-') << endl;

    cout << "Give me a time (such as 3:57) and a duration" << endl;
    cout << "(such  1:05), and  will tell you the sum" << endl;
    cout << "(that is the time that follows the given time" << endl;
    cout << "by the given duration), and difference (the time that proceeds the given time by that duration)."  << endl;

    cout << "Time: " << endl;
    int timeHours;
    int timeMinutes;
    char discard;

    cin >>  timeHours >> discard >> timeMinutes;

    cout <<"Duration: " << endl;
    int durationHours;
    int durationMinutes;

    cin >> durationHours >> discard >> durationMinutes;

 int time = timeHours * 60 + timeMinutes;
 int duration = durationHours * 60 + durationMinutes;
 int after = time + duration;
 int before = time - duration;
 int afterHours = after / 60 % 12;
 int afterMinutes = after % 60;
 int beforeHours = before  / 60;
 int beforeMinutes = before % 60;

 cout << endl;
 cout << durationHours <<":" << durationMinutes << " hours after and before, "
 << timeHours << ":"  <<timeMinutes << " is ["  << afterHours   << ":" << setw(2) << 
setfill('0')<< afterMinutes <<", "
 << beforeHours << ":" << beforeMinutes << "]" << endl;
return 0;
}
```

Comment: If you don't receive an answer to your original question, but receive a bunch of comments with tips, it's indicative of the question needing attention or nudges in the right direction. The correct approach is to spend time considering those, and maybe edit your question. Don't just post a nearly-identical question.

Comment: Did you try debugging the program? What about doing the calculation on the paper first? You should ask your teacher about the unclear parts of the assignment.

Comment: @Besco. The point about adding a few days to the time, is that it stops the calculation going negative. It's as simple as that. Just try it and see what happens.

Comment: @john i did this added 1440 (minutes in a day) and it gave me even more errors

Comment: @Besco You need two changes `int time = timeHours * 60 + timeMinutes + 1440;` and `int beforeHours = (before / 60) % 12;`. With both those changes I got the correct results.